# class template with error "is not a type"

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template class as below

```
template<typename T>
class HMM{
    private:
        int states_num;
        int observables_num;
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> t_probs( states_num, std::vector<T>(states_num, T{}) );
    public:
        HMM(int s, int o):states_num(s),observables_num(o){}

    };
```

But I am getting an compilation error 
`error: ‘states_num’ is not a type`, here `states_num` is an `int`, not a type depending on `T`, why I am getting this error?

Comment: `t_probs` looks like you are trying to declare a member function, but the declaration doesn't make any sense. You probably meant to use braces, not parentheses, so that `t_probs` is a data member, brace-initialized.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think you are right, thanks.